# Laravel - MVC and Multiple Views

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller

I have the following URL `example.com/post` with this route `Route::get('/post','PostController@index)`. Furthermore, I have another route and contoller pair: `example.com/comment` and `Route::get('/comment','CommentController@index')`.

Each path is independently navigatable. Now in my index, I would like to combine both of these two together to show comments and posts together.

### What should I do?

1) Make the pair of `Route::get('\','IndexController@index')` and combine two controllers, that is first `echo $commentController->index()` and then `return $postController->index()`.

2)Make a separate view for index and pass it the post and comment data.

3)Neither of these methods are proper and I should do something totally different.

Comment: IMO, you should do like the second option.

Comment: A main disadvantage of the second option is duplication of code. Essentially, everything will be the same, expect the are copied together. Don't you think that is bad practice? I am not entirely sure.

Comment: If you make a controller for the root of your app, say `AppController`, you could query both Posts and Comments in the same `index()` method. You'd be duplicating a bit of functionality, but it's probably the cleanest approach.

Comment: You can use view partials concept. Create a separate blade file to show posts and another one to show comments. Then you can include it on all your views using `@include`

Comment: check this [recipe](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/90/including-a-blade-template-within-another-template)

Comment: if i am using these two a lot, i'll use a composer.

Comment: I suggest you use eloquent models relationship to create a relationship between post and comment. since a post has many comments and comments has many posts. This will minimize the number of queries you are to make

Comment: @Digitlimit, yes, the models would be connected through Eloquent but my question is regarding the controllers and views. I will go with what staurt-wagner and gabriel-moretti have said.